# Is it possible to match all attributes in a preg_match with empty or missing attributes?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm having a little bit of an issue with `pre_match`.

I have a string that can come with attributes in any order (eg. `[foobar a="b" c="d" f="g"]` or `[foobar c="d" a="b" f="g"]` or `[foobar f="g" a="b" c="d"]` etc.)

These are the patterns I have tried:

```
// Matches when all searched for attributes are present
// doesn't match if one of them is missing
// http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dHi
$pattern = '\[foobar\b(?=\s)(?=(?:(?!\]).)*\s\ba=(["|'])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1)(?=(?:(?!\]).)*\s\bc=(["'])((?:(?!\3).)*)\3)(?:(?!\]).)*]'

// Matches only when attributes are in the right order
// http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dHj
$pattern = '\[foobar\s+a=["\'](?<a>[^"\']*)["\']\s+c=["\'](?<c>[^"\']*).*?\]'
```

I'm trying to figure it out, but can't seem to get it right.

Is there a way to match all the attributes, even when other ones are missing or empty (`a=''`)?

I've even toyed with `explode` at the spaces between the attributes and then `str_replace`, but that seemed too overkill and not the right way to go about this.

In the links I've only matched for `a="b"` and `c="d"` but I also want to match these cases even if there is an `e="f"` or a `z="x"`

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/C9sx3z). It can get all the key-values from a given separate string. The [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD1xI6/1) is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `[...]` strings as separate strings, not inside larger text, it is easy to use a `\G` based regex to mark a starting boundary (`[some_text`) and then match any key-value pair with some basic regex subpatterns using negated character classes.

Here is [the regex](https://regex101.com/r/gF6hX3/1):

```
(?:\[foobar\b|(?!^)\G)\s+\K(?<key>[^=]+)="(?<val>[^"]*)"(?=\s+[^=]+="|])
```

Here is what it matches in human words:

- `(?:\[foobar\b|(?!^)\G)` - a leading boundary, the regex engine should find it first before proceeding, and it matches literal `[foobar` or the end of the previous successful match (`\G` matches the string start or position right after the last successful match, and since we need the latter only, the negative lookahead `(?!^)` excludes the beginning of the string)
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces (they are necessary to delimit tag name with attribute values)
- `\K` - regex operator that forces the regex engine to omit all the matched characters grabbed so far. A cool alternative to a positive lookbehind in PCRE.
- `(?<key>[^=]+)` - Named capture group "key" matching 1 or more characters other than a `=`.
- `="` - matches a literal `="` sequence
  -`(?<val>[^"]*)` - Named capture group "val" matching 0 or more characters (due to `*` quantifier) other than a `"`
- `"` - a literal `"` that is a closing delimiter for a value substring.
- `(?=\s+[^=]+="|])` - a positive lookahead making sure there is a next attribute or the end of the `[tag xx="yy"...]` entity.

[PHP code](http://ideone.com/C6xNnf):

```
$re = '/(?:\[foobar\b|(?!^)\G)\s+\K(?<key>[^=]+)="(?<val>[^"]*)"(?=\s+[^=]+="|])/'; 
$str = "[foobar a=\"b\" c=\"d\" f=\"g\"]"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches["key"], $matches["val"]));
```

Output: `[a] => b, [c] => d, [f] => g`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function:

```
function toAssociativeArray($str) {
    // Single key/pair extraction pattern:
    $pattern = '(\w+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"';
    $res = array();
    // Valid string?
    if (preg_match("/\[foobar((\s+$pattern)*)\]/", $str, $matches)) {
        // Yes, extract key/value pairs: 
        preg_match_all("/$pattern/", $matches[1], $matches);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i += 1) {
            $res[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
        }
    };
    return $res;
}
```

This is how you could use it:

```
// Some test data:
$testData = array('[foobar a="b" c="d" f="g"]',
             '[foobar a="b" f="g" a="d"]',
             '[foobar f="g" a="b" c="d"]',
             '[foobar f="g" a="b"]',
             '[foobar f="g" c="d" f="x"]');
// Properties I am interested in, with a default value:
$base = array("a" => "null", "c" => "nothing", "f" => "");
// Loop through the test data:
foreach ($testData as $str) {
    // get the key/value pairs and merge with defaults:
    $res = array_merge($base, toAssociativeArray($str));
    // print value of the "a" property
    echo "value of a is {$res['a']} <br>";
}
```

This script outputs:

```
value of a is b
value of a is d
value of a is b
value of a is b
value of a is null
```